# Converting from SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR to string and back again doesn't work

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

**Simple test program to illustrate idea:**

*'MyBuildSecurityDescriptor' is a function copied from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446595%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create a basic security descriptor.*

```
PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSecDesc = MyBuildSecurityDescriptor();

// Convert to a PISECURITY_DESCRIPTOR to view the contents.
PISECURITY_DESCRIPTOR piSecDesc = (PISECURITY_DESCRIPTOR)pSecDesc;

LPTSTR szSecDesc;
ConvertSecurityDescriptorToStringSecurityDescriptor(pSecDesc, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION,
                                                    DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION | GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION | OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION | SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
                                                    &szSecDesc,
                                                    NULL);

// At this point szSecDesc has the correct security descriptor in it.
// "D:(A;;KR;;;WD)(A;;KA;;;BA)" for those interested.

// Now to convert back from string version.
PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSecurityDescriptor;
ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor(szSecDesc, SDDL_REVISION_1, &pSecurityDescriptor, NULL);

// Convert to a PISECURITY_DESCRIPTOR to view the contents.
PISECURITY_DESCRIPTOR piNewSecDesc = (PISECURITY_DESCRIPTOR)pSecurityDescriptor;
```

Here are the debug views in visual studio for *piSecDesc* and *piNewSecDesc* for the above program;
[image: Debug view of piSecDesc][image: Debug view of piNewSecDesc]

So my question is why does the SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR after the conversions not have the correct data?

Given that [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/library/aa376401%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states (about ConverStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor) "This function retrieves a security descriptor that the ConvertSecurityDescriptorToStringSecurityDescriptor function converted to string format." I would assume this simple program would work.

**Some context**
My work requires me to retrieve a SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR then pass this, via a pipe, to another program. The easiest way it seemed was to convert to a string, pass it across, then convert back on the other side.

Comment: Did you check the return values of the Convert functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect that the differences you're seeing are because `MyBuildSecurityDescriptor` builds an [absolute security descriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721532%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_security_absolute_security_descriptor_gly), while `ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor` builds a [self-relative](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_security_self_relative_security_descriptor_gly) security descriptor.  You can convert self-relative security descriptors to absolute security descriptors using [`MakeAbsoluteSD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379264%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but quite honestly, there's no real point to it; all Windows APIs accept absolute or self-relative security descriptors.

MSDN [explicitly notes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379561%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the description for the SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR structure:

> Because the internal format of a security descriptor can vary, we
>   recommend that applications not modify the SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR
>   structure directly. For creating and manipulating a security
>   descriptor, use the functions listed in See Also.

I would use the [`IsValidSecurityDescriptor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379147%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function (as well as checking return values) to verify the consistency of your descriptors.

Comment: Exactly.  In a self-relative security descriptor, the "pointers" contain an offset rather than an actual pointer.  The debugger, not knowing about this, tries and fails to interpret them as pointers.

Comment: Just what I needed! Although I guess I don't actually need to use MakeAbsoluteSD if all the APIs accept either type. In the real code I am checking the return values, which is where some of my confusion came in as they returned successfully, but I will add in checks for IsValidSecurityDescriptor. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ralara - the nice thing about self-relative security descriptors is that they're a blob, which means that you can send the self-relative SD across a pipe without having to do a string encode/decode.  You can use [MakeSelfRelativeSD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379265(v=vs.85).aspx) to convert absolute SDs to self-relative format.